# accessing the scriptlet variable in the struts2 <s:if> tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

**i have created variable in scriptlet in the following way in my jsp**

```
<% int count= 0; %>
```

Based on some conditions i am incrementing the variable value...... (**think now 'count'  value is 5** )

**Now i have to do some process if the *'count'* value is *0* by using struts2 tags**

i have tried the following ways. But i failed................

```
<s:if test="#count == 0" > 
   --------
   -------- 
</s:if>  

<s:if test="%{#count == 0}" >  
</s:if>
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Why are you doing it with a scriptlet? There's no need to. In any case, you need to put the scriptlet variable into a normal JSP scope (or onto the value stack, but easier to just put it into scope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone has told you it isn't a good idea... If you want a bad idea then:

Following must be at top of JSP:

```
<%@ page import="com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext" %>
<%@ page import="com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack" %>
```

Following someplace inside your JSP:

```
<%
    int i = 0;
    ValueStack stack = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();
    stack.getContext().put("varName", i);
    stack.setValue("#attr['varName']", i, false);
%>
```

then this should work:

```
<s:property value="#varName"/> <!-- prints 0 -->
```

I didn't take the time to test this but that is how the struts2 set tag does its job (if not a good idea it's still a bit educational ).

Comment: Thank you. Its bad way. But my requirement is like that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use scriptlets

```
<s:bean name="org.apache.struts2.util.Counter" var="counter">
   <s:param name="first" value="0"/>
   <s:param name="last" value="5" />
</s:bean>

<s:iterator value="#counter">
  <li><s:property /></li>
</s:iterator>
```

It will print 0 to 5.

Comment: although if it's going to be used in an iterator the status attribute would be even better...